# Extending a control's capabilities

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Let's say I want to extend all textboxes in my toolbox to do something in particular when the 'GotFocus' event is raised. 
Say, run a line of code that instructs them to SelectAll();

What's the most efficient way I can tack this behaviour/handling of an event to all my TextBoxes?

I'm just using TextBox as an example, as I have plans to do similar things to other controls in my WPF arsenal going forward.

Comment: Using a behaviour as suggested by @17 of 26 would be one way. Creating a custom TextBox control and use this one instead of the built-in TextBox control is another one.

Comment: @mm8 actually, now you mention that i already have a few of these controls set up as UserControls, each with their own bits and pieces of code behind. What i'm really after is avoiding repeat code. I could just take the code i want, and apply it to the code behind of each of these controls and it'd all work just fine, but like i say i'd like to avoid this repetition as much as possible and have these common instructions in one place.

Comment: You should not put the common code in the UserControls but in a custom TextBox control class that you use in all UserControls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to accomplish this using an attached behavior.  Below is code that I currently use to do this and it covers a couple of quirky edge cases.

```
public class TextBoxBehaviors
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllOnFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectAllOnFocus",  typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxBehaviors), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectAllOnFocusChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty GetSelectAllOnFocus(TextBox element)
    {
        return (DependencyProperty)element.GetValue(SelectAllOnFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectAllOnFocus(TextBox element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SelectAllOnFocusProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSelectAllOnFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = d as ComboBox;

        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            comboBox.Loaded += ComboBox_Loaded;
            return;
        }

        var textBox = d as TextBox;

        if (textBox == null) { return; }

        if ((bool)e.OldValue)
        {
            textBox.PreviewMouseDown -= TextBox_PreviewMouseDown;
            textBox.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
        }

        if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
            return;

        textBox.PreviewMouseDown += TextBox_PreviewMouseDown;
        textBox.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
    }

    private static void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        var comboText = comboBox?.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox) as TextBox;

        comboText?.SetValue(SelectAllOnFocusProperty, comboBox.GetValue(SelectAllOnFocusProperty));
    }

    private static void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) { return; }

        // We need to dispatch this in case someone is changing the text during the GotFocus
        // event.  In that case, we want to select it all after they're done.
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                   (Action)(() => TextBox_DoSelectAll(textBox)));
    }

    private static void TextBox_DoSelectAll(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (!textBox.IsFocused) return;

        textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }


    private static void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) { return; }

        if (textBox.IsFocused)
            return;

        textBox.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;  // Prevent default TextBox behavior from deselecting text on mouse up
    }
```

}

Usage:

```
<TextBox beh:TextBoxBehaviors.SelectAllOnFocus="True" />
```

Or set it on all text boxes:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="beh:TextBoxBehaviors.SelectAllOnFocus" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Excellent, I've started using behaviours more and more now, they're very useful.